# Can I reduce this asynchronous code using built in fetch()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

There seems to be an extra `then` method

```
  getUser () {    
    const options = {
      credentials: 'include'
    };
    fetch("/api/user", options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
```

I would like to reduce to:

```
  getUser () {    
    const options = {
      credentials: 'include'
    };
    fetch("/api/user", options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
```

Wrather than just test it out and see if it works I would like to try and understand why it was written the first way an if it is good practice.

**Update**

Why are their two promises for only 1 asynchronous event?

Should not parsing JSON be a simple synchronous function call?

Or is this just a design choice that we can make any function asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` returns a promise.  Their version logs out the result of that promise. Your version would log out the promise object in a pending state, not the value it resolves to.

Comment: O.K.  Why though are their two promises for only 1 asynchronous event?

Comment: I always assume asynchronous events were for unknown things like network calls, file read time etc. but I guess in practice any function can be asynchronous, such as making setTimeout asynchronous?

Comment: I'm not certain why the fetch api was implemented that way. My assumption is that some data and/or processing is available quickly, while other data takes longer. So if you only need the first data you can wait for the first promise and then be done sooner, but if you need everything you can wait for both.

Comment: promises are all the rage these days!